# Databinding Not working inside dynamic fature module

Tags: android, android-databinding, dynamic-feature-module

I have been recently working on the Dynamic Feature Module, inside that Databinding is not working at all and giving runtime error that cannot find class.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.dynamic-feature"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"


    dataBinding {
    enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(":app")

   
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

  

}
```

Please help how can I enable databinding inside my feature module.